# JSON being converted, how to convert back to object with ascii text

Tags: javascript, json

I am saving out a JavaScript object to localstorage using JSON.stringify().

```
localStorage.setItem('stored_object', JSON.stringify(objCases) );
```

Periodically, I will find that the JSON string has spontaneously changed **from this:**

```
{"9999999999999":{"case":"dummy","subj":"example","note":"placeholder"}}
```

**into this:** [(here's why)](https://github.com/vincentamari/SuperSweetAdmin/blob/master/jssource/src_files/include/JSON.js#L122)

```
{asynchronous_key:'577b3620-8cbd-5251-b526-5882044f1386', jsonObject:{"\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039":{"\u0063\u0061\u0073\u0065":"\u0064\u0075\u006d\u006d\u0079","\u0073\u0075\u0062\u006a":"\u0065\u0078\u0061\u006d\u0070\u006c\u0065","\u006e\u006f\u0074\u0065":"\u0070\u006c\u0061\u0063\u0065\u0068\u006f\u006c\u0064\u0065\u0072"}}}
```

As Pointy has finally persuaded me, it is the same information, just wrapped in a "security envelope" -- I need to get the original object out of that envelope.

How can I retrieve the original JSON object from that "envelope"?

### Update

I re-opened this question because in spite of `GoTo 0`'s helpful answer, I am still having difficulty converting the retrieved string to the object. GoTo0's answer began with an object, I must begin with a string formatted exactly as in the below demo:

The error I am getting is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 1`

```js
var str = '{asynchronous_key:\'2e3b7cfc-906d-046e-31d5-5884c338d859\', jsonObject:{"\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039":{"\u0063\u0061\u0073\u0065":"\u0064\u0075\u006d\u006d\u0079","\u0073\u0075\u0062\u006a":"\u0065\u0078\u0061\u006d\u0070\u006c\u0065","\u006e\u006f\u0074\u0065":"\u0070\u006c\u0061\u0063\u0065\u0068\u006f\u006c\u0064\u0065\u0072"}}}';
console.log(str);
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var orig = JSON.stringify(obj.jsonObject);
console.log(orig);
```

Comment: *I will find that ...* — How? What makes you think that that's happening? Are you using some sort of debugging tool? Logging to the console?

Comment: Also note that `"\u0039"` is exactly the same as `"9"`. They're JavaScript unicode escape sequences, not HTML entities. Similar, but different.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. Yes, I am retrieving the stored object from localstorage `localStorage.getItem("stored_object")` and console.logging it. It is well established that this is happening - I discovered this a few days back and am now getting round to solving it.

Comment: Well the strings in your retrieved object are precisely identical to the strings in your original object; what you're seeing is just weird behavior from the console. (What browser are you using?)

Comment: Google Chrome `Version 55.0.2883.87 m`. I am using the stored object in a continuous loop, and reading the object in other browser tabs. There is a small possibility of collisions as there may be 10+ browser tabs all running their own loops and reading the same localStorage object (same domain, a browser-based ticketing system) while one tab may be writing to it. It will take from minutes to hours to days for the localStorage item to be corrupted, but eventually it happens. Being able to quickly convert it back as GoTo0 has demonstrated will resolve this nicely.

Comment: Again, **no "conversion" is necessary.**  The string `"\u0039"` is `===` to the string `"9"`, because `\u0039` means "9".

Comment: Also where is that `"asynchronous_key"` property coming from? Why is the object you saved wrapped in another object?

Comment: Hi @Pointy, So I found out where the async key property is coming from - it appears to be [related to this](https://github.com/vincentamari/SuperSweetAdmin/blob/master/jssource/src_files/include/JSON.js#L122) (that is the CRM/OSS I am manipulating). And although I understand your comment about the string `"\u0039"` being `===` to `"9"`, I cannot put `"\u0039"` on the screen for the user. It may be trivial, but I am not aware how to turn that back into English text. It appeared that `GoTo 0`'s answer was.. the answer... but I must work with a retrieved string and it's not working the same.

Comment: This is the last time I'll write this: the string `"\u0039"` is **exactly the same** as the string `"9"`.  That's not an esoteric scientific theory: it's simple fact. Either string introduced into an HTML document will look like `9` on the screen.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I've been doing everything in console.log, where they are clearly not the same. Your last sentence was a huge light bulb. Thanks! *So now I just have to figure out how to extract the original object out of that string (it seemed simple with GoTo0's example, but once again I am missing something.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how your JSON got converted into that format, but you can easily extract the original object from the value of the `jsonObject` property and format it with `JSON.stringify`.

```js
const data =
      {asynchronous_key:'577b3620-8cbd-5251-b526-5882044f1386', jsonObject:{"\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039":{"\u0063\u0061\u0073\u0065":"\u0064\u0075\u006d\u006d\u0079","\u0073\u0075\u0062\u006a":"\u0065\u0078\u0061\u006d\u0070\u006c\u0065","\u006e\u006f\u0074\u0065":"\u0070\u006c\u0061\u0063\u0065\u0068\u006f\u006c\u0064\u0065\u0072"}}};

const originalJSONString = JSON.stringify(data.jsonObject);

console.log(originalJSONString);
```

BTW, `"\u0039"` is called an *escape sequence*. Here, it stands for the Unicode character with hexadecimal code 0x39 or 57, i.e. the digit "9".

Comment: Testing now... if it's that simple, you've just saved my weekend. Thanks GoTo0.

Comment: There''s really no need whatsoever for any conversion. It's just weird console behavior.

Comment: I'm on now @crashwap. Just go on and post your question, if I can't answer maybe someone else will.