# Fixing corrupted JSON from localStorage

Tags: javascript, json

I am saving out a JavaScript object to localStorage using `JSON.stringify()`.

```
localStorage.setItem('stored_object', JSON.stringify(objCases) );
```

Periodically, I will find that the JSON string has spontaneously changed **from this:**

```
{"9999999999999":{"case":"dummy","subj":"example","note":"placeholder"}}
```

**into this:**

```
{asynchronous_key:'577b3620-8cbd-5251-b526-5882044f1386', jsonObject:{"\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039":{"\u0063\u0061\u0073\u0065":"\u0064\u0075\u006d\u006d\u0079","\u0073\u0075\u0062\u006a":"\u0065\u0078\u0061\u006d\u0070\u006c\u0065","\u006e\u006f\u0074\u0065":"\u0070\u006c\u0061\u0063\u0065\u0068\u006f\u006c\u0064\u0065\u0072"}}}
```

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765063/json-being-converted-to-entities-how-to-convert-back), user `GoTo 0` provided a solution, but I am having difficulty implementing it. I think I am missing something basic:

[**JS Fiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4n6dqqvn/)

**Stack Snippet Example:**

```js
var badjson = {asynchronous_key:'49098507-12cd-e1b0-b442-5882cd1bf37e', jsonObject:{"\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039":{"\u0063\u0061\u0073\u0065":"\u0064\u0075\u006d\u006d\u0079","\u0073\u0075\u0062\u006a":"\u0065\u0078\u0061\u006d\u0070\u006c\u0065","\u006e\u006f\u0074\u0065":"\u0070\u006c\u0061\u0063\u0065\u0068\u006f\u006c\u0064\u0065\u0072"}}};
localStorage.setItem('remindObj', JSON.stringify(badjson));
console.log('Here 03: '+ localStorage.getItem('remindObj') );

var getjson = localStorage.getItem('remindObj');
console.log('Here 06: ' +getjson);
console.log(typeof(getjson));
console.log(getjson.indexOf('asynchronous_key') );
if (getjson.indexOf('asynchronous_key') > 0){
  console.log('ASYNCHRONOUS_KEY FOUND - Attempting to fix');
  originalJSONString = JSON.stringify(getjson.jsonObject);
  console.log('FIXING: ' +originalJSONString);
  objRemind = JSON.parse(originalJSONString);
  localStorage.setItem("remindObj", originalJSONString);
  console.log('FIXED: ' +localStorage.getItem("remindObj") );
}
```

Comment: _"Periodically, I will find that the json string has spontaneously changed"_ Can you describe "spontaneously changed"?

Comment: @crashwap, could you try to change this line: `originalJSONString = JSON.stringify(getjson.jsonObject);` into this: `originalJSONString = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(getjson).jsonObject);`. Does this fix your issue?

Comment: It's in the question: `from this` is how it is initially stored in localStorage, and how it appears after being retrieved -- until some unknown corrupting event takes place and transmogrifies the LS item into `into this` format. I have no explanation on how/why the LS item is being changed, but it is happening. I suspect it is an artifact of the enterprise OSS system that I am working with, and over which I have no control.

Comment: are you using SugarCRM ?

Comment: @dandavis - lol - how did you figure that out? Yes indeed, that's the culprit. Tables for formatting and identical IDs all over the page. blech.

Comment: @GOTO0 Please post that as an answer - it did solve the problem in the jsFiddle. I will now attempt to implement into my project. Thanks ***again*** !

Comment: someone tried to upgrade sugarCRM's JSON routine: https://github.com/vincentamari/SuperSweetAdmin/blob/master/jssource/src_files/include/JSON.js#L122

Comment: @dandavis Very interesting. I wonder if I should switch to using cookies, or if the above code kludge will suffice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json being converted (to entities?), how to convert back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765063/json-being-converted-to-entities-how-to-convert-back)

Comment: @crashwap It's ok. Just note that `getjson` is a *string*, and the syntax `getjson.jsonObject` returns `undefined`, while `JSON.parse(getjson)` returns an *object* with a property `jsonObject` that can be accessed normally. I think this is the only thing you were missing in your code.

Comment: Its quite literally a duplicate. couldn't you just ask there what you were doing wrong?

Comment: @GOTO0 I am still getting an error in my app - any ideas? [Screenshot](https://s23.postimg.org/s899f3t8b/so1.jpg) The line that is failing is the line in question.

Comment: @crashwap Not sure if it's your own code or one of the libraries you are using. The argument to `JSON.parse` should be a string and valid JSON. This is not happening here, hence the error. I'd use a debugger to see the value of the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you can close this: You had an error in line 11 (counting the empty line): It should be `JSON.parse()` not `JSON.stringify()`

Edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4n6dqqvn/1/

```js
var storageKey = 'remindObj';
var badjson = {
  asynchronous_key: '49098507-12cd-e1b0-b442-5882cd1bf37e', 
  jsonObject:{
    "\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039\u0039":{
    "\u0063\u0061\u0073\u0065":"\u0064\u0075\u006d\u006d\u0079","\u0073\u0075\u0062\u006a":"\u0065\u0078\u0061\u006d\u0070\u006c\u0065",
      "\u006e\u006f\u0074\u0065":"\u0070\u006c\u0061\u0063\u0065\u0068\u006f\u006c\u0064\u0065\u0072"
    }
  }
};
localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(badjson));

var getjson = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
console.log('Initial: ', getjson);

if (typeof(getjson) === 'string'){
  console.log('ASYNCHRONOUS_KEY FOUND - Attempting to fix');
  var originalJSONString = JSON.parse(getjson).jsonObject;
  console.log('FIXING: ', originalJSONString);
  localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(originalJSONString));
  console.log('FIXED: ', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey)));
}
```

Comment: This was the answer provided by GoTo0 in the comments, as you well know since you participated in the comments several minutes after he left that answer. As further evidence that you simply appropriated his answer, you left the variable with the name `originalJSONString` and just turned it into an object. Yes, your example works but it does not answer the question that was asked and appears to be a thinly-veiled attempt to game the system, as evidenced by your performance since joining SO four days ago. -1

Comment: the json is stored as string in localstorage. i just logged it as object as you probably always want to work with objects in javascript. Also: the variable is named that way because i edited your fiddle as i already said and that had that variable-name that i didn't change